# TextUtils setError() displays in wrong EditText field

Tags: java, android

Looking for some advice and help with TextUtils `setError()` message is displaying in the wrong EditText. I am checking all the EditText's to make sure they are not left blank and that part is working, it is just only pointing to the very first EditText field instead of the correct one that was left blank and I would like to find out how to get it pointing to the correct one. I have messages all labeled to what EditText is missing as you will see from the screenshot below, the background hint 'Input Value...' is empty and is what the `setError()` is pointing to by the custom label, but the warning exclamation is at a totally different EditText field. How may can I fix this? I am just calling the `setError()` message like this:
 `someEditText.setError(custom message here)`. Thanks all.

See `setError()` screenshot:

[image: setError()]

Here is the code I am using for the EditText fields.

```
 /* Using the Pipe class setters to set the values collected from the editText fields. */
        /*
        Implementing the TextUtils.isEmpty() method for all text fields that are Strings in nature
        to check for empty values. Surrounding all those EditText fields that capture doubles with
        a try/catch and calling a custom Toast message for them to the user. All of the messages
        state exactly which EditText field was left empty.
         */
        newPipe.setJointId(etPipeId.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeId.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+DISPLAY_PIPE_ID+" field");
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setJointNum(etPipeJtNum.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeJtNum.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+DISPLAY_PIPE_JT_NUM+" field");
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setJointHeat(etPipeHeat.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeHeat.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+DISPLAY_PIPE_HEAT+" field");
            return;
        }

        try {
            newPipe.setJointLength(parseDouble(etPipeLt.getText().toString()));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    ,EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+DISPLAY_PIPE_LT+" field",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setJointManufacturer(etPipeManufacturer.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeManufacturer.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_JOINT_MANUFACTURER
                    +" field");
            return;
        }

        try {
            newPipe.setWallThickness(parseDouble(etPipeWallThick.getText().toString()));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    ,EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+DISPLAY_JOINT_WALL_THICKNESS+" field",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setGrade(etPipeGrade.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeGrade.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_GRADE
                    +" field");
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setCoatingType(etPipeCoatType.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeCoatType.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_JOINT_COAT_TYPE
                    +" field");
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setCoatingThick(etPipeCoatThick.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeCoatThick.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_JOINT_COAT_THICKNESS
                    +" field");
            return;
        }

        try {
            newPipe.setSizeDiameter(parseDouble(etPipeSizeDiameter.getText().toString()));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    ,EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_JOINT_DIAMETER +" field",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setCurrentLocation(etPipeLocation.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeLocation.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_CURRENT_LOCATION
                    +" field");
            return;
        }

        try {
            newPipe.setCuts(parseDouble(etPipeCuts.getText().toString()));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    ,EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_CUTS +" field",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            newPipe.setNewLength(parseDouble(etPipeNewLt.getText().toString()));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    ,EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_NEW_LT +" field",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setChildJointId(etPipePup.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipePup.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_CHILD_JT_ID
                    +" field");
            return;
        }

        newPipe.setNotes(etPipeNotes.getText().toString());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeNotes.getText().toString()))) {
            etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+ DISPLAY_NOTES
                    +" field");
            return;
        }

        /* Inserting the collected data from above into the insertPipe() method*/
        if (dbHelper != null) {
            dbHelper.insertPipe(newPipe);
        }
        finish();
        if (dbHelper != null) {
            dbHelper.close(); /* closing the database down here to prevent resource leaks.*/
        }

    } /* savePipe method ends here. */
```

Comment: could you add some code maybe the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

The problems lies in **Edit Text** you are using to call setError(String message) on

```
    newPipe.setJointId(etPipeId.getText().toString());
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeId.getText().toString()))) {
        etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+DISPLAY_PIPE_ID+" field");
        return;
    }

    newPipe.setJointNum(etPipeJtNum.getText().toString());
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty((etPipeJtNum.getText().toString()))) {

        // You are using etPipeId instead of etPipeJtNum
        etPipeId.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+DISPLAY_PIPE_JT_NUM+" field");

        // Use this instead
        etPipeJtNum.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+DISPLAY_PIPE_JT_NUM+" field");

        return;
    }
```

Hope this solves your problem.

**EDIT**

Suggestions to remove repetitive code and easier debugging as requested in the comments. This is how I would write my code. There might be better way to organize and structure the code but I am learning as well :)

```
private boolean checkEditTextIsEmpty(EditText et, String errorMessage){
    // Code Separate for easier reading
    String text = et.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        // Can consider using String.format();
        et.setError(EMPTY_VALUES+"\nPlease fill-in the "+errorMessage+" field");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

//This is your function that you called newPipe.setJointId
boolean isIdEmpty = checkEditTextIsEmpty(etPipeId, DISPLAY_PIPE_ID);
if (isIdEmpty) return;

boolean isNumEmpty = checkEditTextIsEmpty(etPipeJtNum, DISPLAY_PIPE_JT_NUM);
if (isNumEmpty) return;

newPipe.setJointId(etPipeId.getText().toString());
newPipe.setJointNum(etPipeNum.getText().toString());
```

Comment: OMG I feel so stupid. That was careless error on my part when copying/pasting one completed editText to the next and not correcting which actual EditText it was for. Since the etPipeId was the first one, I copied it over to the rest and didn't even catch it. Thanks so much. My problem is solved. Another set of eyes can't ever hurt I am a firm believer now. Thanks again.

Comment: Haha, glad that I could be of help =). I have made similar mistakes in the past when I was starting out and I need to repeat my codes.

If it solved your problem, perhaps you can mark this as question, upvote and thus closing the question?

Comment: A suggestion from me would be you might want to create a separate function for a similar kind of error checking, throwing in the EditText as the method parameter to perform the check first and finally newPipe.setJointId() when no error is detected.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I am still relatively new to Android and Java so how would you go about implementing something like that? A rough example would help me to understand it. Or even better, point me to some resources to learn how to do that. Where could I search to learn? Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Not sure what this coding pattern is called but its basically helps to tidy up your code. I will update my answer above and you could help mark this answer as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked perfectly. I really appreciate the help and I am marking this as accepted.